# How do I reset the Jupyter/IPython input prompt numbering?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I just wrote my first extensive Python tutorial using IPython notebooks.   All went well, except I did a lot of testing and moving blocks around.   How do I reset the `In [ ]:` numbering?  I have tried quitting and reloading, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 77):

From the <kbd>Runtime</kbd> menu, select <kbd>Restart runtime</kbd>.

If you want to run the script again, you can instead select <kbd>Restart and run all</kbd>.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: There is now an option under Kernel "Restart & Run All" which does the same thing with a single click now as Vlad Bezden mentions below.

Comment: Another valid option that clears all those numbers at the left side is on the top bar:  >"Kernel"  >"Restart and Clear Output". you then confirm by clicking "Restart and Clear All Outputs" and you´ll have the same notebook, but without any input numerations.

Answer (score 22):

Every `.ipynb` file can be opened in an editor. Everything written there is in plain text (JSON). For each cell which has the `"cell_type": "code"` there'd be another key-value pair as `"execution_count": <number>`. As you might have guessed, that is the prompt numbering. Hence, if the notebook contains code which will take time to execute (as was, in my case) this method would be time efficient.

Now, either you can manually change each `execution_count` or write a simple script to get the numbering right. To check the results just refresh the notebook in the browser without stopping the kernel. And, everything will be as per your needs, even all the variables/loaded data will remain in the environment.

Comment: +1, for those of us who came here asking how we can reset the execution numbers *without* rerunning the entire notebook.

Comment: @JulianDrago Yeah, my notebooks take hours or even days to run sometimes… restarting kernel certainly not usually an option merely just to reset execution numbers.

Comment: For those who want to search-replace via regex: `(?<=("execution_count": ))\d+`

Answer (score 20):

You can reset the kernel (shortcut: `C-m .`) and re-run the whole notebook.

Quitting and reloading doesn't work because the code is not re-evaluated.

Comment: I just figured it out.  In the menu  Cell > All Output > Clear

Comment: `Cell > All Output > Clear` just clears the output, it doesn't reset the numbering... `Kernel > Restart` does it.

Answer (score 15):

```
'Kernel' -> 'Restart & Run All'
```

Just make sure you saved your Notebook. You can also bind/assign keyboard key for running this command.

```
'Help' -> 'Edit Keyboard Shortcuts'
```

Comment: thanks! I added "Ctrl-Shift-R" to "restart kernel and run all cells".

Answer (score 7):

If what you want is to remove the numbers themselves, so that each cell shows `In [ ]` (instead of something like `In [247]` which is leftover from some previous incarnation of the kernel), use "Cell" > "All Output" > "Clear" (in Jupyter Notebook 5.4.0) or "Edit" > "Clear All Outputs" (In Jupyter Lab 0.32.1).

This will remove all the numbers, even if you're in the middle of running a notebook.  It will not reset the numbering back to 1;  e.g. if the last cell you executed was 18, the next will be 19.

If you're using this because you want clarity about which cells you've executed during this run of the kernel and which cells you haven't executed yet, use "Cell" > "All Output" > "Clear" (or "Edit" > "Clear All Outputs") immediately after you start (or restart) the kernel.  This can be useful when restarting a kernel, or when opening a saved or duplicated notebook.

This will also remove all outputs from the notebook.

Thanks to user2651084 in a previous comment for this.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit too late, but I had the same problem, and since my notebook had cells with execution time up to 5 minutes, I had to wait a long time until **Restart & Run All** finished.

So I've made a Python script to make this task for me:

```py
import json

file = '/your/notebook/path/Notebook.ipynb'

# Since every notebook is actually a JSON (JavaScript
# Object Notation), then its contents can be represented
# in a dictionary (or a list of dictionaries)
with open(file, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    nb = json.load(f)

count = 1
for cell in nb['cells']:
    # Markdown cells doesn't have execution count,
    # so apply this only to cells that have one
    if 'execution_count' in cell:
        cell['execution_count'] = count
        count += 1        

    # Not all code cells have output, such as functions
    # that return None or simple declarations, so apply
    # this only to cells that have some output
    try:
        for output in cell['outputs']:
            if 'execution_count' in output:
                output['execution_count'] = cell['execution_count']

    except KeyError:
        continue

with open(file, 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(nb, f, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

But be careful with the execution order and the variables in your cells, since applying the script above on your notebook can generate a different output if you run the notebook again. For example, let's suppose your notebook have the following cells with the execution order in square brackets:

```
In [2]: a = 1
```

```
In [1]: a = 2
```

```
In [3]: a

Out[3]: 1
```

If you apply the above script into your notebook, it'll show the following:

```
In [1]: a = 1
```

```
In [2]: a = 2
```

```
In [3]: a

Out[3]: 1
```

But if you run the notebook again, it'll show the following:

```
In [1]: a = 1
```

```
In [2]: a = 2
```

```
In [3]: a

Out[3]: 2
```

This can be a bit confusing for people who are downloading your notebook via GitHub for example, since they can see an output in the repository, but when they run on their machine, the output will be different.

Answer (score 2):

`Cell > All Output > Clear` Clear all `In []:` numbers but do not reset them back to 1 for the next cell you run.

`Kernel > Restart & Clear Output` Restart the kernel, clear output, clear `In []:` numbers and reset them to 1, and clear output.

Answer (score 2):

`Restart & Run All` isn't a good solution, because simply I don't want to run all (and that's the purpose of a notebook to run things cell by cell).

Anyways, I found this solution more plausible:

```
Main Menu > Cell  > All Output > Clear
```

Answer (score 1):

For those coming from Google:

```
%reset
```

This is useful when you want to reset all variables after a certain point in the notebook. It is going to ask if you are sure that you want to reset. If you want to force reset without asking, then use:

```
%reset -f
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to clear the execution numbers to `[ ]` **without re-running the whole notebook**:

1. Just to be safe, make a copy of your notebook:

```
cp notebook.ipynb notebook_copy.ipynb
```

2. Open your notebook with vim:

```
vim notebook.ipynb
```

3. In vim, reset the execution numbers with the following search-replace command:

```
:%s/"execution_count":.*/"execution_count": null,/gc
```

4. You will then get the following prompt. Type `a` to replace all occurrences:

```
replace with "execution_count": null, (y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y)? a
```

5. Save notebook and quit vim:

```
:wq
```