# How do I reset the IPython input prompt numbering? (console, not notebook or qt)

Tags: ipython

The following is my current IPython command prompt (regular terminal IPython, not the notebook, or Qt):

```
In [45]:
```

I'm done with my workflow, and am moving on to a new task. I'd like a way to reset the IPython input prompt number as follows:

```
In [1]:
```

I understand this may be possible from non-duplicate question to which I cannot reply nor answer for my case: [How do I reset the IPython input prompt numbering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817690/how-do-i-reset-the-ipython-input-prompt-numbering)

For further clarity, an example of the command I'm after:

```
In [99]: %reset_command_number
In [1]: 2+2
Out[1]: 4
In [2]: %reset_command_number
In [1]:
```

**The 3 Magic Questions**:

1. Does such magic (%reset_command_number) exist?
2. If the answer to 1 is yes, what dark magic is it?
3. If the answer to 1 is no, is this achievable from a lower level IPython api? (yes i've searched the api docs and no i did not find a way to do it, yet...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to modify the `execution_count` of the [InteractiveShell](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py):

```
import IPython; IPython.get_ipython().execution_count = 0
```

- Using a one line command with `;` makes it easier to call this repeatedly (if you use up-arrow to scroll the command history)
- This has the side effect that after first command you will also see this error. *I do not know if it has any side effects, though. (it already says that the history logging was moved to another session)*

```
ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session 20741
```

## Demo

```py
In [1]: a = 1

In [2]: b = 88

In [3]: c = 99

In [4]: import IPython; IPython.get_ipython().execution_count = 0

In [1]: a
Out[1]: 1

ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session 20767
In [2]: b
Out[2]: 88

In [3]: c
Out[3]: 99

In [4]: import IPython; IPython.get_ipython().execution_count = 0

In [1]: a = 15

ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session 20768
In [2]: a
Out[2]: 15

In [3]: b
Out[3]: 88
```

#### Using an alias?

It is also possible to use an alias for the command. For example, create file `i_reset.py` and put it into your `site-packages`, `~/.ipython/extensions/`, your  `PYTHONPATH` or any other folder you can see in your `sys.path`

```py
# i_reset.py

def i_reset(line):
    """
    Reset IPython shell numbering to [1]    
    """
    import IPython; IPython.get_ipython().execution_count = 0

def load_ipython_extension(ipython):
    """This function is called when the extension is
    loaded. It accepts an IPython InteractiveShell
    instance. We can register the magic with the
    `register_magic_function` method of the shell
    instance."""
    ipython.register_magic_function(i_reset, 'line')
```

Then, you may use the extension by first loading it and then calling it like so:

```
In [4]: %load_ext i_reset

In [5]: i_reset

In [1]: a
Out[1]: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can, and what is done with the notebook is equivalent (from what I understood) to just open a new python session as if you open a new tab and start ipython again, and re-execute everything.

So, if I were you and had to start a new task and want to start at `In [1]` I would just start a new ipython environment.

The equivalent with ipython notebook to start a new task would be to start a new notebook.

The only reason I can imagine why you would do this is that you want to access some variable from the previous task. 
What I would is to save the object you want to re-use using pickle or by saving a variable into a file an reload it in a new ipython session.

Did you looked at the Doc on [Input caching system](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html?highlight=prompt#input-caching-system) ? You may have answer to other question relative to yours.

Note that I'm aware that's not really an answer, but it's a bit more than just a comment, anyway, I hope this helps !

If you have more specific needs than just reseting the prompt number, just detail them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need the session data, the simplest is to exit and restart IPython.

```
$ ipython
In [1]: 1+1
Out[1]: 2

In [2]: 2+2
Out[2]: 4

In [3]: 3+3
Out[3]: 6

In [4]: exit

$ ipython
In [1]: print("Prompt numbering reset")
Prompt numbering reset

In [2]:
```